# Why should extremely small difference in H2O versions (3.13.0.337 vs 3.13.0.341) be incompatible?

Tags: version, h2o

My colleague and I installed slightly different versions of H2O.  It doesn't seem right because you can't even tell from the download page ( https://www.h2o.ai/download/ ) which exact minor version you are downloading:

```
 pip install http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-deepwater/public/nightly/latest/h2o-3.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

He got the error:

```
Server error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Error: Found version 3.13.0.337, but running version 3.13.0.341
  Request: POST /99/Models.bin/
```

I humbly suggest that 3.13.0.X be compatible with 3.13.0.Y

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not recommended/supported, you can start h2o with the parameter strict_version_check=False when calling h2o.init()

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/starting-h2o.html

Comment: I tried that to no avail...  Error: Found version 3.13.0.337, but running version 3.13.0.341

Comment: Please post the code you used to start up the H2O cluster.  `strict_version_check = False` should work.